# How to install Windows 7 upon ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

Please any body say How to install windows 7 on ubuntu 14.04 dual boot
would be a Big help if explained in Step by step !!

Comment: What do you mean by "upon Ubuntu" ? On virtualbox?

Comment: Also please remember that the disk can only support 4 simple partitions - if your windows installation has put additional support partitions down you may have to sacrifice some to make one for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Step-by-step setup instructions for Window/Ubuntu dual-boot from the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot), scroll about half-way down for Windows installation on current Ubuntu set-up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough time see also this tutorial: [Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/).
I used this tutorial to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 and it worked :)

However my partion table look a bit different. If it'll help you I put the screenshot of it below:
[image]